# Query Mysql vs Node JS didn't return any result

Tags: mysql, node.js, select

I make a connection to mysql using node js,

connection is successful, event if i put a wrong port,

but query didn't return any results.

mysql version for node js is :  "mysql": "^2.18.1"

data base version : 5.5.47

(port : number or string : same result)

```
    var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
//
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'mydb',
    user : 'root',
    password: 'pwd',
    port : '3306'


});


connection.connect(function(error){
    if(!error){
        console.log(error)
    } else{
        console.log('Connected')
    }
});


    connection.query("SELECT * FROM members", function(error, rows){
        if(!error){
            console.log("Error in the query")
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            console.log("successfull")
            console.log(rows)
        }
    })


app.listen(4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following logic is incorrect. it says if not error then log error so you will never get your rows.

```
if(!error){
            console.log("Error in the query")
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            console.log("successfull")
            console.log(rows)
        }
```

Remove the `!`